# Demon Slayer Mugen Train: Differences Between Movie and TV Anime

Tags: demon-slayer-kimetsu-no-yaiba

The movie was out before already.

But then after quite a while then came out the TV Anime with 7 separated episodes.

So my question is: Why did they need to do the extra series? What was the difference between the extra series and the original movie?

Comment: Length?  More plot?

Comment: Plot-wise there's no difference, the anime is just the movie chopped into episodes, anime movies are often considered non-canon, so the episodes are a way of maintaining continuity since the events occurred in the movie are indeed canon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences are:

- The first episode of the anime series wasn't included in the movie.
- Each episode at the end has an extra clip, usually like a joke, which wasn't included in the movie.

Also obviously more money for also adding the anime series too.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely think the additional episodes were just to continue generating revenue. The viewers love demon slayer so why not profitize off of it? It also gives the viewers more to imagine/love about the series with the extra clips at the end of each episode.

I also find the episodes afterwards to be more accessible for people that cannot sit through the entire more. Breaking it up into pieces makes it more ingestible and gives something to look forward to to others that may live an incentive-based life.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/91960)